# wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences

Tags: callback, web-component, class-method, custom-element

**Update March 2023**

Note: this works because in the next *tick* your **N** (not all!) DOM elements IN lightDOM will have been parsed.

for (app.) **N > 1000** you will run into trouble, as the *delay* will end before all N Elements are parsed.

So either add (about 20 lines) of code that actually **checks** all lightDOM is parsed. (but since your DOM is then suffering Obesitas, you will probably also have other performance problems)

**Or just keep the N amount of DOM elements *inside* lightDOM small.**

Ofcourse any DOM you **add** later, **after parsing**, doesn't affect anything (when the `connectedCallback` doesn't fire)

**Update March 2021:**

FireFox bug fixed, now behaves the same as Chromium and Safari.

That means waiting for the JS EventLoop to be empty (with `setTimeout` or `requestAnimationFrame`) in the `connectedCallback` is now a cross-browser method

```
connectedCallback(){
 setTimeout(()=>{
   // can access lightDOM here
 }); // ,0 not required
}
```

What the heck is the Event Loop? - Philip Roberts
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

---

---

**Update Oct. 28 2020:**

- Now reported by Mozilla engineer Anne van Kesteren as a bug in FireFox:

  FireFox invokes the connectedCallback too late:
  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1673811

---

---

**First post May. 2020:**

Bitten again by this Chrome Element upgrade issue, after spending a week in FireFox.

Forgot to wrap code in a setTimeout before delivering to Chromium browsers.

- FireFox prints: **ABCD**
- Chromium prints: **ADCD**

**Question:** Why the difference?

```html
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML);// "A" in FireFox, "" in other Browsers
      if (this.innerHTML == "A")
        this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + "B";
      else
        setTimeout(() => this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML + "D");
    }
  })
</script>

<my-element>A</my-element><my-element>C</my-element>
```

Related answers over the past years:

- [How to have a 'connectedCallback' for when all child custom elements have been connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48663678/how-to-have-a-connectedcallback-for-when-all-child-custom-elements-have-been-c)
- [How to wait for Custom Element reference to be "upgraded"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196503/how-to-wait-for-custom-element-reference-to-be-upgraded/39220992#39220992)

#### Update #1

- Apple/Safari: prints: **ADCD**  (same as Chromium)

note: Chromium Blink engine is a fork of Apples [(WebKit)WebCore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) code!!

### Update #2

With Supersharps reference we found the related threads:

- (2016) connectedCallback timing when the document parser creates custom elements
  https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/551
- (2019) Need a callback for when children changed or parser finished parsing children
  https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/809

#### order of callbacks in FireFox versus Chromium:

source: https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/9p5qyk1z/

[image]

Comment: Why do you say that it's Chome that is wrong and not Firefox? or that it's just a difference in the way they interpret the (maybe unclear) spec?

Comment: Safari prints: **ADCD**

Comment: Struggling with a use-case. Seems wrong to be interrogating the text node?

Comment: @Supersharp, in Firefox there is no need for any delay(tricks) ``connectedCallback`` is what it says.. Element is connected and available. If the spec is unclear I would say Mozilla got it right. @Berniev, code is per example to show the difference in Browsers; Chromium/Safari requiring the ``setTimeout``... since the *error* is also in Safari I suspect a deeper down/not Custom Element related issue .. because Chromiums Blink engine(2013) is a fork of Apples (WebKit)WebCore code.

Comment: # **note:** FireFox ``connectedCallback`` trigger was wrong and has been fixed by Mozilla in **March 2021**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the Chrome/Safari behaviour is less intuitive for the beginners, but with some more complex scenarios (for example with child custom elements) then it is much more consistant.

See the different examples below. They act strangely in Firefox...

Another use case that I don't have the courage to code: when a document is parsed, maybe you don't have the end of the document yet. Therefore, when a custom element is created, you cannot be sure you get all its children until you get the closing tag (that could never arrive).

According to Ryosuke Niwa for WebKit:

> The problem then is that the element won't get connectedCallback until
>   all children are parsed. For example, if the entire document was a
>   single custom element, that custom element would never receive
>   connectedCallback until the entire document is fetched & parsed even
>   though the element is really in the document. That would be bad.

So it's better no to wait and connect the custom element as soon as it is created, that means with no child.

```html
<script>
    customElements.define( 'c-e', class extends HTMLElement {} ) 
    customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
      connectedCallback() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML, this.childNodes.length)
        let span = document.createElement( 'span' )
        if (this.innerHTML.indexOf( 'A' ) >= 0 )
            span.textContent = 'B'
        else
            span.textContent = 'D'
        setTimeout( () => this.appendChild( span ) )
      }
    })
</script>
<my-element>A</my-element><my-element>C</my-element>
<br>
<my-element><c-e></c-e>A</my-element><my-element>A<c-e></c-e></my-element>
<br>
<my-element><c-e2></c-e2>A</my-element><my-element>A<c-e2></c-e2></my-element>
```

As far as I understand, there was a consensus on it that led to adjust the spec that (Chrome/Safari) way:

> Fixes [w3c/webcomponents#551](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/551) by ensuring that
>   insertions into the DOM trigger connectedCallback immediately, instead
>   of putting the callback reaction on the the backup element queue and
>   letting it get triggered at the next microtask checkpoint. This means
>   connectedCallback will generally be invoked when the element has zero
>   children, as expected, instead of a random number depending on when the
>   next custom element is seen.

We can conclude that Firefox also follow the spec... yes, but we should not rely on the content in `connectedCallback` for the reasons discussed above.