# How to Get the Contents of a Custom Element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm creating a [custom element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) that will be able to convert its contents from markdown to HTML. However, I'm not able to get the contents of my custom elements.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
   <template id="mark-down">
      <div class="markdown"></div>
   </template>
   <!-- Converts markdown to HTML -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/showdownjs/showdown/dist/showdown.js"></script>
   <script>
      customElements.define('mark-down',
         class extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
               super()
               let template = document.querySelector('#mark-down').content
               this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(template.cloneNode(true))
            }
            connectedCallback() {
               console.log(this) // Returns the whole <mark-down> node and its contents
               console.log(this.innerHTML) // So why does this return a blank string?
               // This should theoretically work --> let markdown = this.innerHTML
               let markdown = '## Test'
               let converter = new showdown.Converter()
               let html = converter.makeHtml(markdown)
               this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = html;
            }
         });
   </script>

   <main>
      <mark-down>
## Our Markdown

These contents should get converted

* One
* Two
* Three
      </mark-down>
   </main>
</body>
</html>
```

My issue is in the `connectedCallback()`. When logging `this`, I get the whole `<mark-down>` node with its contents in markdown. However, it doesn't seem to have valid properties. Using `innerHTML` returns a blank, where it should return the markdown; other combinations, like `this.querySelector('mark-down')`, return `null`.

What can I do to get the contents of my custom element?

Comment: I tested your code with Firefox 68.2.0esr and I don't get a blank string, but the full markdown. What is your browser?

Comment: @Amessihel Edge/Chromium. I'll give it a go in another browser. If so there's likely a polyfill.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have been bitten by ***this*** so much, I purposely asked a StackOverflow question for people to find

**[wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)**

The easiest workaround is a `setTimeout` in the `connectedCallback`

```js
<script>
  customElements.define('my-element', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      console.log(this.innerHTML);// "" in all Browsers
      setTimeout(() => {
        // now runs asap 
        console.log(this.innerHTML); // "A"
      });
    }
  })
</script>

<my-element>A</my-element>
```

What this and all mentioned workarounds do is postpone code execution until the DOM is fully parsed.
`setTimeout` runs after `DOMContentLoaded`, but if you wrap **everything** in `DOMContentLoaded` the whole Element creation runs late, same applies for `defer` or placing `<script>` at the end of your page

Supersharp explains the why better in:

[wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)

Comment: If I'm correct, this is the best answer, because there won't be [FOUCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)

Answer (score 3):

After some research online, I found the [following nugget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) about `connectedCallback`: *each time the custom element is appended into a document-connected element. This will happen each time the node is moved, and **may happen  before the element's contents have been fully parsed**.*

Therefore, depending on the browser, `innerHTML` may not in fact be defined when being used. That's why the above snippet, while fine in Firefox, doesn't work in Chrome or Edge.

To solve this problem, place the `script` tags at the bottom of the `body`, in which case the element will be parsed first, and the script will know what `innerHTML` contains.

Another way around this is to wrap the custom element constructor inside a DOM loaded event. That event would look like so:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e) => {
   class markDown extends HTMLElement {
      ...
   }
}
```

Yet another way of doing this is putting your script in a separate file, and marking the `script` tag with the `defer` attribute.

All three solutions work whether or not the class is explicitly named and defined by a separate statement, as mentioned by Triby's answer, or anonymous and wrapped by the custom element definition function, as in the original question.