# QuerySelector on a Custom Element

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I want to select the icon with the id='home-i' and give at an on-click effect; however, when I use `document.querySelector('left-navbar nav');` it returns as `null`. I am using a basic javascript custom element, which appears to be causing the problem.

I have tried using shadowRoot and using a setTimeout trick as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962138/how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-custom-element). Both methods didn't seem to work.

The `<left-navbar></left-navbar>` is the custom element.

```
  <body>
        <main>
            <!-- Heading -->
            <h1 id='reading-heading'>Chapter 1</h1>

            <!-- Navigation Bar -->
            <left-navbar></left-navbar>
```

Custom component

```
class Navbar extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.innerHTML = `
            <nav id='navbar'>
                <i class="fas fa-home" id='home-i'></i>
                <hr class="line">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left" id='back-i'></i>
                <i class="fas fa-brain"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-lightbulb" id='quiz-i'></i>
                <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" id='exit-i'></i>
            </nav>
            `
        });
    }
}
customElements.define('left-navbar', Navbar)
```

Javascript using query selector

```
const homeBtn = document.querySelector('left-navbar nav');

homeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
    changePageTitle(0);
})
```

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to add the event listener after the `<nav>` element is added?

Comment: Why are you using `setTimeout()` to add the innerHTML?

Comment: I was trying to follow the advice from that link. I was about getting the contents of a custom element, which is what I want to do.

Comment: A custom element seems a little overkill for what is essentially a function that returns HTML formed by a template string.

Comment: If I understand the other question correctly, you only need to do this if you're trying to read the `innerHTML` of the element.

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell if I am adding the event listener after or before the element. And I'm not sure how to guarantee the order that they are added in.

Comment: Good point, it does seem that is not what I am trying to do. No wonder it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `setTimeout` makes its function execute **after** the EventLoop is cleared,
so *after* all other JS code is parsed.

See the code below, `other code` is displayed in the console, and then `setTimeout` is displayed.

Thus when *you* tried to add a Click handler, there was no HTML **yet** to use `querySelector` on.

If the click handler is tied to the Web Component, then add the click handler **inside** the Web Component.

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => console.log("setTimeout"));

      this.innerHTML = `<nav>Element Nav InnerHTML</nav>`;
      this.querySelector("nav").onclick = (evt) => alert("clicked!");
    }
  });
  console.log("other code");
  // your addEventListener was here
</script>

<my-element></my-element>
```

Notes:

- As mentioned in the comments `setTimeout` is required when you want to **READ** the Web Component **(lightDOM)** `innerHTML` in the `connectedCallback`; because the `connectedCallback` fires on the *opening* tag, so its innerHTML isn't parsed yet. `setTimeout` executes after all DOM and (inline) JS is parsed.
  Deep dive in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences) SO post
- I use an **inline** `onclick` Event listener here; `addEventListener` is for use cases where you (might) want to add multiple listeners on one DOM element.
  See: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)
- You can also do: `this.onclick = (evt) => alert("clicked!");`