# Obtain this.textContent during Custom Element Construction

Tags: javascript, constructor, web-component, lifecycle, custom-element

This is a conceptual question for those who understand [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/) without seeing concrete code examples.

I'm creating a custom element that's display depends on its textContent. In the custom element's constructor, if I try to access `this.textContent` it returns an empty string, even though the html of that custom element does indeed contain text.

In order to obtain the `textContent` during the custom element's construction, I enclosed my constructor code within a setTimeout and then was able to make my custom elements construction be base on its `textContent`.

However, this felt a little hacky and I figured there was a more proper way to obtain textContent during an element's construction. That's when I found [Using the life Cycle Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks).

The `connectedCallback` method allowed me to see textContent without putting a setTimeout into the custom element's constructor. However, this quote concerns me:

> connectedCallback: . . . may happen before the element's contents have
> been fully parsed.

This worries me that if I have a lot of content inside the custom element, `this.textContent` may still return an empty string because all that text may not yet be "fully parsed".

Is this worry justified? Is there a more sure way to obtain `this.textContent` as a basis for your custom element's construction? Or, should I go with my initial solution of putting a setTimeout within the custom element's constructor?

Comment: No need to hurry, 'aliens' have more advanced technology and master time travel, thus the whole concept of 'hurry' doesn't apply.... https://www.space.com/aliens-time-traveling-humans-ufo-hypothesis.html

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thanks, Danny. It seems you've already thought this through :) Do you have a link to an example of the concept you mentioned [here](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/889#issuecomment-704930044)? If not, no worries; I'll try it out soon.

Comment: It is an HTML tag **_inside another_** HTML tag. If that is too complex I  have to shield you from more errors... okay, okay... here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/Lhcsd2m5/

Comment: Great, thanks! However, I'll warn you: because of your knowledge, I've added you to my list of suspected aliens (with Elon Musk). @Danny'365CSI'Engelman

Comment: We're not aliens, only alienated. Michael J. Fox was great in that movie; but once you go *back* you can't **go** back. We are *"guides"* from the future, now stuck in the same time-travel mode you are in. Well.. I am a *guide*. Elon is just a pot smoking idiot, who is doing some things right for a better future; so we chose not to *"re-direct"* him.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/Lhcsd2m5/ now has updated code... alas this is a drawback of regular *forward time travel*, enhancements are **never** published in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `textContent` is DOM content

The `constructor` should not (try to) access DOM,
as it can be run from  `.createElement('your-element')`  when there is no DOM at all.
(or in a Server-Side-Rendering scenario)

`connectedCallback` runs before the whole DOM inside finished parsing. If you want to access its DOM content you have to wait till Element DOM is ready.

Only in FireFox you *can* access Element DOM content;
see: [wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)

For detailed analysis see: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/n20bwckt/
Note the difference when run in FireFox and Chrome.

#### setTimeout( func , 0 )

is totally valid (but better not in the `constructor`) and ensures your code runs when the EventLoop is empty, thus when all DOM is ready to be accessed. You could also use `requestAnimationFrame`.
All libraries do something similar under the hood to add `updateComplete` and the likes.
With *bare-bones* Custom Element API you have to write it yourself.

**Note:** The `connectedCallback` now triggers code that runs **after** a (potential) `disconnectedCallback`, so check for that with `this.isConnected` in your code.

For visual diagram when all callbacks run see:
https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/

Note: if you don't specify any methods in your own Element, the methods from HTMLElement run.
So Elements without any declared `constructor` or `connectedCallback` are perfectly valid.
In [IconMeister](https://iconmeister.github.io) I only use `attributeChangedCallback`

Comment: [Roger that](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/roger-that/), [Danny](https://i.imgur.com/Lj398Xq.png)! Thanks for bringing all these considerations to my attention.

Comment: Does `attributeChangedCallback` fire during the initialization/modification of element content (such a `this.textContent` or `this.innerHTML`)? The name implies it would only fire if an HTML attribute has changed and I wouldn't expect that to fire during the initialization or modification of element content.

Comment: I updated [the JSFidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/n20bwckt/) It shows **observed**-attribute value _FIRST_ fires the ``attributeChangedCallback`` **BEFORE** the ``connectedCallback``. That is why most examples check for ``oldValue===null`` in the ``attributeChangedCallback``