# LitElement - ForEach children in template

Tags: typescript, foreach, children, lit-element

I want to create `<slot>`s for each child, so for example here I have a menu and I want each child to be placed inside a `<div>` with `item` class.
I have created a little utility function to map the children:

```
export function ChildrenMap(el: LitElement, map: (el: HTMLElement, index: number) => TemplateResult): TemplateResult[] {
    console.log(el.children.length) // Returns 0 in Google Chrome and I guess Edge too.
    return (Array.prototype.slice.call(el.children) as HTMLElement[])
                .map(map);
}
```

And then I am using it in the render function:

```
render() {
    return html`
        <nav>
        ${ChildrenMap(this, (ele, index) => {
            let id = ele.id ? ele.id :  `item-${index}`;
            ele.setAttribute('slot', id);

            let klass = 'item';
            if(this.selected && this.selected == index) {
                klass += " selected";
            }

            return html`
                <div class="${klass}" data-index="${index}">
                <slot name="${id}"></slot>
                </div>`;
        })}
        </nav>
    `;
}
```

This works fine in FireFox, but as my comment above says, in Google Chrome, the element has 0 children at the point of render, so the `<nav>` is empty.
Can anybody explain why the element has 0 children at the point of render?
Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, does anybody have any alternatives to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: I have mentioned this [in a LitElement GitHub issue](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-element/issues/1152)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update: Mozilla/FireFox fixed this bug early 2021

Actually **FireFox is wrong** at this point, it invokes the `connectedCallback` **too late**

Bug confirmed by Mozilla engineer Anne van Kesteren:

- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1673811

For details see StackOverflow thread:

- [wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)

There are no DOM children **to read** yet in the `connectedCallback` because all DOM children are still being parsed. (it could potentially be a very large DOM structure)

The work-around (like you found) is to wait:

```
connectedCallback(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    // now you can access this. DOM children
  },0);
}
```

All suggestions with Promises etc. effectively do the same: **Wait till the Event Loop is empty**

- What the heck is the Event Loop?  - Philip Roberts
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Thank you and thank for the video link... I like the fact that something that work is actually a bug.