# lit-element getElementById in connectedCallback returns null

Tags: web-component, lit-element, lit-html

I remember many web components tutorials say `connectedCallback` is good for hooking up DOM events or getting some DOM elements (like [this one](https://dev.to/bennypowers/lets-build-web-components-part-3-vanilla-components-4on3)). But I couldn't get a simple program to run in lit-element:

```js
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';

class MyElement extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`<p id="root">template content</p>`;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.shadowRoot.getElementById('root'); // null
  }

  firstUpdated() {
    this.shadowRoot.getElementById('root'); // not null
  }
}
```

Looks like it only works in `firstUpdated`, doesn't `firstUpdate` fire after first render? what if I need some events set up before first render? why `connectedCallback` doesn't work here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`connectedCallback` works according to the spec, it just doesn't do what you expect.

Those callbacks fire at different moments in time

```js
<my-element myattribute="foo">   1. -> connectedCallback
  <p id="root">
    template content
  </p>
</my-element>  2. -> firstUpdated (LitElement)
```

`1. -> connectedCallback` means the Element is injected in the DOM.
but its **children** are **not** parsed yet.

Unless you use a FireFox (**pre 2021 version!!**), which fires `connectedCallback` too late at **2.** [(confirmed bug)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1673811)

Think of elements as water hoses; **connect** means the hose is connected to a tap, not that water flows through it. So you can access data-attributes (a property of the hose) in the `connectedCallback`

That is why the `connectedCallback` fires at this `1. ->` moment in time... you may want content based on its attributes. And you don't want to wait for all content to be parsed (which potentially can be a very very large DOM tree)

Also note `connectedCallback` runs **every time** you move the Element in the DOM

And if you dive deeper you will also notice `attributeChangedCallback` runs **before** the `connectedCallback` if you have observerAttributes on your element.

LitElement lifecycle callbacks are **sugar**, they 'safeguard' you against (powerful) bare metal Web Component behaviour.

So without LitElement, you can do:

```js
connectedCallback(){
  // 1. -> do stuff
  setTimeout(() => {//no tricks, just wait till that dreaded JS Event Loop is done
    // all children are parsed
    // 2. -> do stuff
  });
}
```

For gory callback details see: [wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)

Comment: setTimeout - see also: setImmediate from [queue-microtask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue-microtask)

Comment: connectedCallback - see also [firstUpdated](https://lit.dev/docs/components/shadow-dom/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when using a property with a @query()-decorator in Lit 2.5.

There is a handy promise (`this.updateComplete`) that one can use to wait for the dom to update.

```js
@query("#checkbox")
_input! : HTMLInputElement;

async connectedCallback() {
   super.connectedCallback();

   await this.updateComplete;

   this._input.checked = this.checked;
}
```

This also works in other scenarios where you e.g. changes a property that makes something visible in the DOM and then need to access that element in the same method.

```js
@query("#checkbox")
_input! : HTMLInputElement;

_showMyElement() {
   this.showCheckbox = true;
   
   // wait for the DOM to update
   await this.updateComplete;
   
   // grab the element
   this._input.checked = this.checked;
}
```