# web component behaves differently depending on "defer" being used or not

Tags: typescript, web-component

I implemented a WebComponent in TypeScript that looks like this and is bundled via a WebPack:

```
class MyTestComponent extends HTMLElement {
    // ...
    connectedCallback() {
        this.config = JSON.parse(this.innerText);
// ...
customElements.define("my-test", MyTestComponent);
```

In the web page it is used like this:

```
<my-test>
{
  "parts": [
    [3, "red"]
  ]
}
</my-test>
```

This worked fine using my WebPack genrated test page, but failed if I included the component into another page. I spend some time until I figured out that the `defer` attribute at the including script tag makes the difference. If I use `defer` the component works fine. If not `this.innerText` is empty when `connectCallback` is called.

I would like to understand why `defer` makes a difference and what's going on in detail. Can somebody explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with TypeScript or WebPack. This is standard Web Components behavior.

**The `connectedCallback` fires on the *opening* tag, its inner content is not yet parsed.**

With `defer` you declare the  Custom Element ***AFTER* everything in the DOM is parsed**

So to make it work when your Custom Element is **defined *BEFORE* being used**,

you have to delay execution till the Components DOM (`innnerText or innerHTML`) is parsed.

Easiest is to delay till the Event Loop is empty:

```
connectedCallback() {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.config = JSON.parse(this.innerText);
  });
}
```

Long answer (when Firefox fired `connectedCallback` late, prior to March 2021)

- [wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)

BaseClass **Tools**, like FAST, Lit, LWC and Hybrids, shield you from this standard behavior...
...making you learn a Tool, *not* the Technology.