# DOM Events (DOMContentLoaded) in a web component

Tags: web-component, native-web-component

I've created a native Web Component (HTMLElement) and I am using it to expose an otherwise existing component (lowercase 'c') that is a fragment comprised of HTML/CSS/JS ... basically wrapping it in Web Component to help with its re-use and isolate it from the rest of a Web page.

The problem is the component i'm including in my Web Component has some JavaScript to lazy load images, and it lists for the `DOMContentLoaded` document event to trigger some of its JS which manipulates the DOM (injects the proper `<img>` tag) ..

I am able to get everything into my Web Component, and execute the component's JS within the `shadowRoot` (with `mode: open`) however the component's event listeners on `DOMContentLoaded` are never invoked.

I tried writing everything in my Web Component in both the `constructor()` as well as `connectedCallback()` but they acted the same.

1. Does a Web Component/ShadowDOM have its own DOMContentLoaded event? And/or does it respect the parent DOM's "state"?
2. If I execute JS in the context of the Web Component that binds an event listener for `document...` does that event listener apply only to the ShadowDOM? Or is that actually being bound to parent DOM?

UPDATE: I am loading my Web Component asychronously - so it's loaded after the parent's natural DOMContentLoaded event triggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, there is no `DOMContentLoaded` Event for the Web Component.
   `connectedCallback` triggers when the Web Component is injected(connected) into the DOM.
2. Yes, you can bind Events anywhere in the DOM and have access to everything in the DOM
   (when using shadowDOM, that is one of the main differences with IFrames.. which can't access its "container")

**Notes:**

- By your description, it sounds like `DOMContentLoaded` has passed; thus I presume you are defining Web Component **late** (are you loading scripts `async`?)

  **IF** you create/load your Web Component ASAP **synchronously** (or define as a script in the head)
  you *can* catch the `DOMContentLoaded` Event

  But in general you shouldn't count on that behaviour as the user/developer is/should be in control on when scripts/components load.
- The `connectedCallback` triggers on the **opening** tag of your Web Component. If the Web Component was ***defined*** **early** The DOM ***after*** the opening tag will not have been parsed yet.
  Many libraries like Lit and Hybrids and Stencil provide methods *like* `onUpdated` that "help" or "prevent" you making *mistakes* ... you are learning a Tool, *not* the Technology.

  In vanilla JS you have to create that behaviour yourself; easily done by adding a 0ms `setTimeOut` inside your `connectedCallback`. That effectifly waits till the EventLoop is empty and triggers when all DOM is parsed.

  FireFox fired `connectedCallback` **late** for a long time, they fixed it March 2021
  Long explanation: [wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)

Comment: I do load the WC async. I assume there isnt't  the WC emits on connectedCallback that i could update the external JS to listen for? Though - i think i should emit my own even and listen for that as i dont know what other WC's might be on the page that could emit said event (if such a thing even exists)

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Emit an Event in the ``connectedCallback``, so other (existing) components know the state (I hate that word)