# Can't set textContent of a customised built-in element except in timeout

Tags: javascript, custom-element

I'm making a customised  element that automatically localises it's visual text representation:

```js
class LocalDate extends HTMLTimeElement {
  // Specify observed attributes so that
  // attributeChangedCallback will work
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["datetime"];
  }

  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    const self = super();

    this.formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.languages, {
      year: "numeric",
      month: "short",
      day: "numeric"
    });

    return self;
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (name === "datetime") {
      this.textContent = "";
      const dateMiliseconds = Date.parse(newValue);
      if (!Number.isNaN(dateMiliseconds)) {
        const dateString = this.formatter.format(new Date(dateMiliseconds));
        this.textContent = dateString;
      }
    }
  }
}

customElements.define('local-date', LocalDate, {
  extends: "time"
});
```

```html
<time is="local-date" datetime="2022-01-13T07:13:00+10:00">13 Jan 2022 - Still here</time>
```

The kicker is when exactly the script tag is run - if it's run after the body is parsed, then it works as expected. Otherwise, instead of appearing as a date, the element displays the date string *in addition to* the text that was already in the element.

JsFiddle and StackOverflow both put the script tag at the bottom of the body, so the error can only be seen with a DataUrl:

data:text/html;charset=utf-8,%3C%21DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0D%0A%3Chtml%3E%0D%0A%3Chead%3E%0D%0A%3Cmeta%20charset%3D%22utf-8%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Ctitle%3ETime%20since%3C%2Ftitle%3E%0D%0A%3Cscript%3E%0D%0A%09class%20LocalDate%20extends%20HTMLTimeElement%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20Specify%20observed%20attributes%20so%20that%0D%0A%09%09%2F%2F%20attributeChangedCallback%20will%20work%0D%0A%09%09static%20get%20observedAttributes%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09return%20%5B%22datetime%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%09%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09constructor%28%29%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20Always%20call%20super%20first%20in%20constructor%0D%0A%09%09%09const%20self%20%3D%20super%28%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09this.formatter%20%3D%20new%20Intl.DateTimeFormat%28navigator.languages%2C%20%7B%20year%3A%20%22numeric%22%2C%20month%3A%20%22short%22%2C%20day%3A%20%22numeric%22%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09%09return%20self%3B%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%09attributeChangedCallback%28name%2C%20oldValue%2C%20newValue%29%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09if%20%28name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22datetime%22%29%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09this.textContent%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09const%20dateMiliseconds%20%3D%20Date.parse%28newValue%29%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28%21Number.isNaN%28dateMiliseconds%29%29%20%7B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09const%20dateString%20%3D%20this.formatter.format%28new%20Date%28dateMiliseconds%29%29%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20Bizarrly%2C%20this%20doesn%27t%20seem%20to%20work%20without%20doing%20this%20in%20a%20timeout%3F%21%3F%21%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.textContent%20%3D%20dateString%3B%0D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%09%7D%0D%0A%09%7D%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09customElements.define%28%27local-date%27%2C%20LocalDate%2C%20%7B%20extends%3A%20%22time%22%20%7D%29%3B%0D%0A%3C%2Fscript%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fhead%3E%0D%0A%3Cbody%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3ELast%20updated%20%3Ctime%20is%3D%22local-date%22%20datetime%3D%222022-01-13T07%3A13%3A00%2B10%3A00%22%3E13%20Jan%202022%20-%20Still%20here%3C%2Ftime%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E

I've reproduced this in both Firefox and Chrome - any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Could you edit your code so that it will produce the behavior you're trying to solve?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier The error doesn't happen when the script tag is run after the body is parsed (which is always is in StackOverflow snippets and JsFiddle) so I've added a Data url to the bug in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue occurs,
because BOTH `attributeChangedCallback` and `connectedCallback` fire on the **opening tag**
(and in this order!)

So

- when the Custom Element is **defined** ***BEFORE*** being used in the DOM,
- the `attributeChangedCallback` fires on the **opening** tag,
- adds your `.textContent`
- **after** that the **lightDOM** from your Custom Element is **parsed**
- and by default **added** to the existing content

That is why you see the `lightDOM #2` in the example below

```html
<style>
  time {
    display: block
  }
</style>

<time id=BEFORE is="local-date" datetime="2022-01-13T07:13:00+10:00"> lightDOM #1
  <script>console.log("time element BEFORE parsed")</script>
</time>

<script>
  customElements.define('local-date', class extends HTMLTimeElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["datetime"];
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      console.warn("attributeChangedCallback", this.id, this.isConnected);
      this.textContent = (new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.languages, {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "short",
        day: "numeric"
      })).format(new Date(Date.parse(newValue)));
    }
  }, {
    extends: "time"
  });
  console.warn("Custom Element: local-date defined");
</script>

<time id=AFTER is="local-date" datetime="2022-01-13T07:13:00+10:00"> lightDOM #2
  <script>console.log("time element AFTER parsed")</script>
</time>
```

#### Do not do initialisation in the `attributeChangedCallback`

- So we have to make sure thetime is only rendered **after** all DOM is parsed, using a `setTimeout`
  also see: [wait for Element Upgrade in connectedCallback: FireFox and Chromium differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences)
- and.. (but no role in the solution) because Apple has, since 2016, stated they will never implement *Customized Built-In* Elements, make it an *Autonomous* Element `<local-date>`
- You could also add N kiloBytes more and use any of [the 58 Tools for building Web Components](https://webcomponents.dev/new), some shield you from this low level behaviour. *But a Fool with a Tool, is still a Fool.*
- Good reference for when callbacks execute: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/
- But `attributeChangedCallback` DOES run before `connectedCallback`!
  Note how you can use `this.isConnected`

```html
<style>
  local-date {
    display: block
  }
</style>

<local-date id=BEFORE datetime="2022-01-13T07:13:00+10:00"> lightDOM #1
  <script>console.log("time element BEFORE parsed")</script>
</local-date>

<script>
  customElements.define('local-date', class extends HTMLElement {
    static get observedAttributes() {
      return ["datetime"];
    }
    attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
      console.warn("attributeChangedCallback", this.id, this.isConnected);
      if (oldValue) this.renderTime(newValue);
    }
    connectedCallback(){
      console.warn("connectedCallback", this.id);
      setTimeout(()=>this.renderTime());
    }
    renderTime(dt=this.getAttribute("datetime")){
      console.warn("renderTime", this.id);
      this.textContent = (new Intl.DateTimeFormat(navigator.languages, {
        year: "numeric",
        month: "short",
        day: "numeric"
      })).format(new Date(Date.parse(dt)));
    }
  });
  console.warn("Custom Element: local-date defined");
</script>

<local-date id=AFTER datetime="2022-01-13T07:13:00+10:00"> lightDOM #2
  <script>console.log("time element AFTER parsed")</script>
</local-date>
```

Comment: For the connectedCallback timing problem, there is [`HTMLParsedElement`](https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element) which fixes the missing `webComponentDOMFullyParsed()` callback (which I was so lucky to be able to contribute essential parts to). That being said, in four years of web components development what worked best all the time was to force the upgrade case by delaying the custom element registration to DOMContentLoaded using `defer`, and avoiding `document.write` completely.

Comment: @connexo `defer` seems like it wouldn't help if another of the same custom element was added to the DOM later, so looks like all my custom elements are going to need this "render on connect after delay" boilerplate, which is... disappointing. They really couldn't have just had `connectedCallback` fire after the light DOM was parsed? Or add another callback just for that?

Comment: @Sora2455 From our experience, dynamically adding webcomponents later is not a problem as long as you don't use `document.write` to achieve that.

Comment: But let us not advice to whack on ``defer`` because we do not understand, nor master the technology. #### ``HTMLParsedElement`` does _basically_ the same as a ``setTimeout``, only with a lot more code. The whole point is to wait till the Event Loop is empty, so you know (ligh)DOM was parsed. ####  Being able to dynamically add/upgrade Web Components is one of the great advantages over Frameworks; BUT, it does cause FOUCs you  now (might) have to deal with.