# Can I set attributes and slot text at the same time as instantiating a custom element in JS

Tags: javascript, web-component

If I use a custom element in HTML the provided attributes are all available in the constructor

```
<my-element myparam="fruit">I like bananas</my-element>

constructor() {}
    super()
    this.param = this.getAttribute("myparam")

> this.param = "fruit"
```

But if I create an instance of my custom element in JS with `document.createElement` the constructor runs immediately, without the attributes being available.

```
const elem = document.createElement("my-element")

> this.param = null
```

Once I have appended the element to a DOM node I can hook `attributeChangedCallback` which fires when I call `elem.setAttribute`, to set `this.param`. But that seems kind of ugly. I feel as though you ought not to have to create extra methods just to make a component usable via JS as well as HTML. It seems like there's similar situation with textNodes / Children too.

Is there any way to make attributes and children available to the constructor when creating nodes programmatically?

edit: So it seems seeking to do this is bad practice and I should only try to access attributes in the connectedCallback() function. As long as I use setAttribute before adding the component with .appendChild the values should be available a that point.

Comment: Is it called `my-element` or `my-component`? I doubt that's the issue though

Comment: This seems normal. When we create a link using `createElement('a')` it doesn't have a `href` property set (`""`). So we have to do that manually. Elements have no attributes when created programmatically.

Comment: Your example works because your ``constructor`` ran **after** the ``<my-element>`` DOM was parsed in the page. Never rely on this _edge-case_ behavior! to stay save **never** access DOM in the ``constructor`` (you can ofcourse access the **shadowDOM** of an element if it was created in the ``constructor``)

Comment: Also be aware for **observerdAttributes** the ``attributeChangedCallback`` runs before the ``connectedCallback``. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70691243/cant-set-textcontent-of-a-customised-built-in-element-except-in-timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor runs before the element has attached to the DOM when you use `document.createElement` so you will not be able to access attributes as they don't exist yet.

You can access attributes in connectedCallback. The following basic example works

```
customElements.define(
  "my-el",
  class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
    
    connectedCallback() {
      this.foo = this.getAttribute("foo")
      console.log("foo", this.foo) // logs "bar"
    }
  }
);

const el = document.createElement("my-el");
el.setAttribute("foo", "bar");
document.body.append(el)
```

You have some typos: `my-element` vs. `my-component`, `this.getAttribute("myparam")` when you attribute above is called `param`.