# How can access the specific html tag inside of slot in light DOM through the shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom

I've created a custom element and defined it in html as follows:
`

```
<header>
    <custom-navbar links="[{title:'home'},{title:'About'}]" class="bg-purple">
        <h1 slot="logo">
            Amazon
        </h1>
    
        <navbar  slot="link" class="navbar-wrapper">
            <ul  class="link-container">
               
            </ul>
        </navbar>
    </custom-navbar>
</header>
```

`

An I've defined my custom element as follows:

```
class CustomNavbar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
    
        <style>
           :host(.bg-purple){
                display:flex;
                width:100%;
                background-color:purple !important;
           
            }

            .container{
                display:flex;
                flex-direction:row;
                margin:1rem;
                align-items:center;
            
            }
   
        </style>

        <div class='container'>
                <div>
                    <slot name="logo"></slot>
                </div>
                <slot name='link'></slot>
        </div>
    
    
    `;
    }

     connectedCallback() {
       this._links = this.getAttribute("links");
   
        }
    }

    customElements.define("custom-navbar", CustomNavbar);
```

I am looking for getting the links attribute defined in light DOM in shadow DOM and add the link to ul element? I've also use :`document.querySelector("custom-navbar").querySelector("ul")` inside of `connectedCallback()`, But it didn't work correctly.

Comment: You can help us answering your question, by adding a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click. Thank you.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, Sure, Here you can find the source of question.https://jsfiddle.net/amirtbi/bfu0o1dj/11/#&togetherjs=lo1Rcgn3Rf

Comment: To get all the nodes in your `slot`, you should select the slot and ask for it: `this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'slot' ).assignedElements()`

Comment: @somethinghere, the found assignedElements is an empty array!.

Comment: `this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'slot[name=link]' ).assignedElements()`, as the first `slot` in your dom is actually `name=logo`, which has no assigned elements here.

Comment: @somethinghere, It's an empty array!. I want to add some links  like li elements to its parent (ul). when using this.shadowRoot.queryselector..., the result is just a slot with its name. it does not include anything.

Comment: If you have a child element with a `slot=link` attribute, you should be able to find it by finding the slot with that name and requesting it's `assignedElements()`, if there are none something else must be wrong. However, if you _run this in the `constructor`_, you will get `0` as at that point, the element isn't allowed to have children yet. Try checking for existing elements in `connectedCalback` _or_ by listening for `slotchange` events dispatched by your slot element (`this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'slot[name=link]' ).addEventListener( 'slotchange', ... )`

Answer (score 1):

The `connectedCallback` fires on the opening tag; so there is no parsed lightDOM yet at this stage (unless the CE is defined after DOM parsing).

So you either:

- use `setTimeout` inside the `connectedCallback` to postpone querying for your `<ul>` tag in lightDOM
- add an `insertLI` method on you component that checks/waits for the `<ul>` to exist

The `setTimeout` is totally valid unless you have a very LARGE lightDOM (like  > 750 DOM nodes) then add [HTML-parsed-element code](https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element)

Note:

```
super();
this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `...`
```

can be chained to:

```
super() // sets AND returns 'this' scope
    .attachShadow({ mode: "open" }) // sets AND returns this.shadowRoot
    .innerHTML = `...`
```

Comment: It's so tricky!. Apparently it is necessary to use something like setTimeout().!. But , what about very large light DOM? What is the best practice?

Comment: Use ``setTimeout`` if you have only a handfull of DOM nodes in lightDOM. it will give the browser enough time to parse all its lightDOM. This never failed me in tests with under 750 DOM nodes in lightDOM. All tools like Lit, Stencil etc. do this for you when they provide a **renderedCallback**. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61971919/wait-for-element-upgrade-in-connectedcallback-firefox-and-chromium-differences

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it creates and populates a list of links dynamically within the shadow DOM by using the links attribute provided in the custom element's HTML.

```
class CustomNavbar extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <style>:host(.bg-purple){display:flex;width:100%;background-color:purple!important;}.container{display:flex;flex-direction:row;margin:1rem;align-items:center;}</style>
      <div class='container'><div><slot name="logo"></slot></div><slot name='link'></slot></div>
    `;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    const links = JSON.parse(this.getAttribute("links") || '[]');
    const ulElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("ul.link-container");
    
    links.forEach(linkInfo => {
      const liElement = document.createElement("li");
      liElement.textContent = linkInfo.title;
      ulElement.appendChild(liElement);
    });
  }
}

customElements.define("custom-navbar", CustomNavbar);
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: My problem with  your answer is that, the ulElement value is null!.